# Fancybox hideOnContentClick false does not work

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I don't want my popup to be closed by overlay click, close button click or escape button click.

My Popup content refreshing when I click on content of the popup below are my setting.

```
$('.login_popup').fancybox({
      href : "#addtocart_login_cont",
      hideOnOverlayClick: false,
      hideOnContentClick:false, 
      overlayColor: '#000000',
      showCloseButton: false,
      enableEscapeButton: false,
      scrolling: 'no',
      autoDimensions: true
}).trigger('click');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want my popup to be closed by overlay click, close button click or escape button click.

Then, the only API option you need is `modal: true` as documented for v1.3.4 :

> modal : When true, 'overlayShow' is set to 'true' and 'hideOnOverlayClick', 'hideOnContentClick', 'enableEscapeButton', 'showCloseButton' are set to 'false' (default: false)

so this code will do the trick :

```
$('.login_popup').fancybox({
    href: "#addtocart_login_cont",
    modal: true,
    overlayColor: '#000000',
    scrolling: 'no',
    autoDimensions: true
}).trigger('click');
```

**Note** : this options are for fancybox v1.3.4. If you are using v2.x, `modal: true` will also prevent closing fancybox (check the [proper documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) for the rest of your API options)

**Important** :

If you are using fancybox **v1.3.4** to open *inline* content (as it seems you do), beware of **[this bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fancybox/-re22BoXOzM)** and workaround.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c13hjceb/)** using fancybox v1.3.4